# Embed linked org files in export to latex/pdf

Tags: org-mode

Is it possible to embed linked .org files when exporting to latex or pdf.

I have a top level document which is effectively an index of other .org files, which I would like to export with the linked org files embedded in the export.

Or perhaps I am using org-mode incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the attachfile latex package for this.

```
\attachfile{Somefile.org}
```

This adds the file as a pdf attachment. I have made that link like attachfile:somefile.org so it clicks to open the file but exports to latex

I think you might mean something else though. You might want

```
#+include: somefile.org
```

To include the contents. It is not that easy to do either one of those with file links.